# Looping AVAudioPlayer w/o Gap

Tags: objective-c, avaudioplayer, avaudiorecorder

I'm recording a sound using AVAudioRecorder and then attempting to play back the sound using AVAudioPlayer. I'm trying to get the sound to loop indefinitely, but the sound has a short gap in between loops. I've tried recording the AVAudioRecorder recording to all possible file types, yet I can't find something that will allow seamless looping. Thanks.

Comment: Why downvotes? There are no similar questions where someone is both recording *and* playing back, wanting to loop.

Comment: For many of us it doesn't make sense to downvote questions - problem questions should be either edited or 'sent back' to the questioner for editing.  But that's how the powers that be set it up... Sorry, I know it's unhelpful (especially with a new user).

Answer (score 8):

This is a great post that helped me eliminate loops in my AVAudioPlayer implementation: http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=640862

the gist of the post is that compressed audio adds blank sound to pad out the length of the sample to an even multiple of 1024.  Using uncompressed audio, or audio that is specifically output for the purpose of looping will eliminate the glitch.

Comment: How easy was that? Brilliant!