# AVAudioPlayer loops are not seamless

Tags: ios, avaudioplayer

I am creating and playing an AVAudioPlayer as the following:

```
playerOne = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: URL.init(fileURLWithPath: path))
playerOne.numberOfLoops = -1
playerOne.prepareToPlay()
```

I am playing an AAC file. I am using

```
playerOne.play(atTime: startTime)
```

to schedule a play in future and sync multiple AVAudioPlayers.

All works fine but my problem is when sounds loop they go out of sync, this is due to loops not being seamless.

What happens here is that due to aac decoders I believe that there is an exra small silence is added to the decoded audio data which causes the sync between audio players to be lost. I expected this loop to be perfect with 0 gap between looping from end to beginning.

How may I achieve seamless looping with AVAudioPlayer?

Comment: EXACTLY! I've found the same thing, even though my understanding is that priming/remainder frames should be handled by AVAudioPlayer. Very frustrating. Have you found a workaround? Just to note; in my case it's not a synchronization thing, but just that I'm hearing the gap on loop—basically like the priming/remainder frames aren't being handled.

Comment: @jbm I tried to do the following: have two players, second player starts playing when exactly first player stops. Then this did not work because apperantly Apple API's never gives %100 accurate duration... I was so disappointed on this. I couldnt solve my problem. AudioKit does seamless loop you can check that lib but it has its limitations too, for example I couldnt set its buffer size and the whole file is loaded into ram causing huge mem allocations and waste of mem...

Comment: Actually, I'm using AudioKit, but their AKPlayer just wraps AVAudioPlayer. I guess I can look for alternatives within AudioKit...

Comment: @jbm for seamless looping with AudioKit you must have the following line `player.buffer = true` before you play the player. I used AudioKit and tested it, it can make loops truely seamless, with 0 gaps and loop

Comment: I’m using v4, where the same function is “.buffer = .always” but apparently it doesn’t actually work.

Comment: @jbm Are you sure? Maybe your sample has very small silence at the end of it. Check it with audacity or FL studio. I'm pretty sure Audiokit can seamlessly loop

Comment: Yeah, double-checked the file multiple times. All loop seamlessly. Looking for a solution.

Comment: Well the hardest solution is to write your own sound engine see the discussion here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66834610/how-to-play-decoded-audio-data-through-hardware-on-ios but it is very time consuming and the last resort

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `AVAudioEngine` will give you a lot of flexibility but it's overhead if you don't need anything else but sync your tracks.

In this case you can try to use a single player with `AVComposition` containing all your tracks, something like this:

```
func generateComposition(urls: [URL]) throws -> AVComposition {
    let composition = AVMutableComposition()
    let audioTracks = urls
        .map(AVAsset.init(url:))
        .flatMap { $0.tracks(withMediaType: .audio) }
    
    for audioTrack in audioTracks {
        guard
            let compositionTrack = composition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: .audio, preferredTrackID: kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid)
        else { continue }
        
        try compositionTrack.insertTimeRange(
            audioTrack.timeRange,
            of: audioTrack,
            at: .zero
        )
    }
    return composition
}
```

And play it using `AVPlayer`:

```
AVPlayer(playerItem: AVPlayerItem(asset: composition))
```

Comment: if I want to use AVAudioEngine, what is the replacement for AVAudioPlayer in AVAudioEngine?

Comment: you need to create AVAudioPlayerNode for each track, attack them to engine, like `engine.attach(player)`, and then schedule a file to play for an each player `player.scheduleFile(...)`. After scheduling all files you can run prepare `player.prepare(withFrameCount:)` for each, so when you start it with `player.play()` i'll start immediately. Then you wait each player(you can use completion of `scheduleFile` method) to finish and do all stuff again to start playing

Answer (score 0):

> due to loops not being seamless.

I'm not sure what you mean by "not seamless", but if the problem is that you are experiencing latency, that's pretty much natural with AVAudioPlayer. If the goal is to loop with minimal latency, use AVAudioEngine.

Comment: What I mean is I believe that the encoder adds a small silence to the very end of the decoded file due to decoded packets not being fully filled. Some decoders do this. I encountered this in an ogg decoder too, what do you mean by latency? Is it audio latency aka time it takes for audio to go through devices and be heard through a speaker! A seamless loop is a loop where the end and the beginning has 0 silence in it that would likely be caused by encoders or other reasons. A seamless loop, loops sample perfect with 0 gap and is a perfect loop

Comment: @csguy, you probably solved the problem of silences in loops WAAAAY back in 2021, but I stumbled onto a similar problem more recently and found this: https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/avaudioplayer-avoiding-glitches-when-playing-looped-sounds.640862/ (found via https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13889948/looping-avaudioplayer-w-o-gap)